# How do I get twitter trends in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, twitter, twitter4j

I have been working for the past month in Android Studio trying to get the top 10 trending topics of a specific WOEID. I have been looking around and couldn't find any examples. I did find the Twitter4J library and use it but no one has examples I can use or get help from. I also discovered the socialauth library but no examples out there.

I want to display the top 10 trending topics.

If I need to change anything or implement and use a different library I am okay with that. This is my current Twitter4J code:

**Note** - The values for consumer_key, access_token etc. needs to be replaced with actual values.

```
public List<String> getTrends(AccessToken atoken, int woeid) throws TwitterException {
    woeid = 23424775;

    //twitter.getOAuthAccessToken("2421499634-SC3Lcq4AT57IvaiyIFegZe42GNOWHeBkmarfc9e");

    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();

    cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
            .setOAuthConsumerKey("consumer_key")
            .setOAuthConsumerSecret("comsumer_secret")
            .setOAuthAccessToken("access_token")
            .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("access_token_secret");

    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
    Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

    Trends trends = twitter.getPlaceTrends(woeid);

    List<String> currentTrends = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(Trend t: trends.getTrends()){
        String name = t.getName();
        currentTrends.add(name);
    }
    return currentTrends;
}


public void ListViewTrends (ArrayList<String> currentTrends){
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, currentTrends);

    CanadaT.setAdapter(arrayListAdapter);
}
```

Comment: what is the issue with current implementation?Does above code don't provide you the desired trends?

Comment: well I don't know if the list array is being filled or not. Maybe it is but it doesn't get displayed on my phone when I test it.

I didn't authenticate with OAuth properly.